# SQL remove "-" in all column

Tags: sql, database, replace

i have a table Destinataire. unfotuntaly the clien had enter the symbol "-" in their data.

when i select them:

```
SELECT [CODE_DEST]
      ,[NO_CLIENT]
      ,[RS_NOM]
      ,[ADRESSE]
      ,[CP]
      ,[VILLE]
      ,[INSEE]
      ,[TEL]
      ,[PAYS]
      ,[FAX]
      ,[SIRET]
      ,[EMAIL]
  FROM [Soft8Exp_Client_WEB].[dbo].[DESTINATAIRE]
  WHERE code_dest like '%-%' or RS_NOM like '%-%' or ADRESSE like '%-%' or VILLE  like '%-%'
```

there are about 700 element, it take time to change it one by one.

how can i update all this elment that contains "-" ?
example : MALLET-LIMOUZIN SARL becaome MALLET LIMOUZIN SARL
and BP 325 - 14 AVENUE MICHELET become BP 325  14 AVENUE MICHELET

i just wanna to replace all "-" with " ".

Comment: Take a look at `REPLACE` from SQL, this is a [great](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-replace-in-an-update-statement) article.

Comment: You want to update one column or all columns of this table??

Answer (score 1):

```
update [Soft8Exp_Client_WEB].[dbo].[DESTINATAIRE]
set code_dest = replace(code_dest,'-',' '),
    column2 = replace(column2,'-',' '),
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] = REPLACE([column], '-', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[`Replace()` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)**

The query will be something like

```
update [Soft8Exp_Client_WEB].[dbo].[DESTINATAIRE]
set column = replace(column, '-', ' '),
    otherColumn = replace(otherColumn, '-', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Replace:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
UPDATE DESTINATAIRE
SET FIELD = REPLACE (FIELD , '-' , '')
```

Where field is the field you want to replace.

```
UPDATE DESTINATAIRE
SET code_dest = REPLACE (code_dest , '-' , '')
, RS_NOM = REPLACE (RS_NOM , '-' , '')
, ADRESSE = REPLACE (ADRESSE , '-' , '')
, VILLE = REPLACE (VILLE , '-' , '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the client will be updating the data in future, and also how you will be consuming it, it might be worth creating a SQL View which incorporates the REPLACE statements above. You could then use this as your datasource and avoid any future use of "-" in the data.